# Creating JFrame and getconentpane full-size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, fullscreen

I am using Java, and trying to make my JFrame's size as the size of the window, not to overlap the taskbar. Off-course, I want it to be the exact same size at every screen resolution. Moreover, to make the frame.GetContentPane() size as the size of the frame. Later I will want to create JPanels within the frmae at a constant size.

I have seen many solution, but unfortunately, non of them work for me.
Please help! Thank you very very much.

Comment: Hi, since you said you've seen many solutions but did not work for you, could you kindly provide us with the code you tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, how to set window size to maximum (may be incorrect when computer has more than one display).

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestWindow {

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test max size");
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setSize(
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().getSize());
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Another possibilities are: make frame maximized or use fullscreen mode. Content pane gets the maximum size automatically.

Comment: Thank you, looks fine. Tell me - how can I set the getcontentpane to be the same size accordingly?

Comment: Simply make frame undecorated (without title bar and borders).

Comment: Hi all, thank you all for your help. I still have 2 things troubling me: 1. I have jpanels inside my frame. Their size changes if I change screen resoultion. Every panel is defined with setBounds() method.  2. The frame still overlaps the taskbar. Do you know what do to? thanks again

Comment: 1) You need to start a timer task to poll the screen resolution and change your frame size when you detect the resolution change.
2) Don't use setBounds() method. Use [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) instead. In this case your panels will get new size automatically when you resize your frame.